# Web3j: Get value of transaction token transfered using Transaction Hash

Tags: spring-boot, smartcontracts, web3-java, etherscan

With Web3j **(**not Web3js**)**, how do I get the value of token transferred using transaction hash?

Comment: try to See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154907/9131185

Comment: Thanks @OLIVIERSZINSOU, but my question is for java language (Web3j), the answer you refer to is using javascript from Web3.js

Answer (score 0):

I found this example for web3j:

```
String transactionHash = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
TransactionReceipt transReceipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(transactionHash).send().getTransactionReceipt();
Transaction transaction = ethTransaction.getResult();
int size = tokenImpl.getTransferEvents(transReceipt).size();
size = size -1;
BigInteger valueTransaction = tokenImpl.getTransferEvents(transReceipt).get(size).value;
```

The value will be recieved in BigInteger